# Unable to push project into new GitLab repo: Error: Git access over SSH is not allowed

Tags: git, gitlab

As the title says, I created a new repo on Gitlab under my company's org. When I try to push up an existing folder, it throws this error. My SSH is set up and everything. What am I missing?

Comment: Sounds like a question for your internal IT support services, to be honest, likely related to your that GitLab server is configured.